# How to create a login page in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the Master-Detail application template from Xcode, and I wanted to create a simple login page.  I know how to search for the username-password combinations, but I just don't know how to set the view up in the storyboard.  I have used this:[image] for my storyboard, but whenever I click the button, it leads to the Detail View Controller instead of the Master View Controller.  Also, after I followed the old "Your Second iOS App" tutorial by Apple Developer, the Cancel/Done buttons in the Add View Controller would lead straight back to the login page (it's supposed to lead to the Master View Controller).  In essence, I was wondering... is there another way to make a view that is only accessed one time through the whole usage of the app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` to determine which view controller is shown first on the phone. First you should declare your ViewController as conforming to the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface MyLoginViewController () <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
```

Then in your login view controller's `prepareForSegue:` set it as the delegate of your split view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]])
    {
        UISplitViewController *splitVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        splitVC.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Then add

```
#pragma mark - Split view

- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    if ([secondaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && [[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]] && ([(DetailViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] detailItem] == nil)) {
        // Return YES to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

to your login view controller.

I'm not sure why pressing cancel/done unwinds to your login. I would try changing the segue between your login view controller and split view controller to modal.